# Failure of a Subring to be an Ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Is there any measure of the failure of a subring to be an ideal, using for example homological methods? I just remembered that for $\phi : R\rightarrow S$, where $R,S $ commutative rings with unity, that $\phi^{-1}(\phi(I))=I+Ker\phi$, while $\phi(\phi^{-1}(J))=J\cap Im\phi$, where $I$ an ideal of $R$ and $J$ an ideal of $S$, and it's not as symmetrical as I would want. Of course $Im\phi$ is a subring, and $J\cap Im\phi$ is an ideal of it, but there's something "off-putting" about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question:** "Is there any measure of the failure of a subring to be an ideal, using for example homological methods?"

**Answer:** The following Theorem seems to hold:

**Theorem.** If $R \subseteq S$ is a unital subring which is an ideal then $R=S$.

**Proof:** If $R \subseteq S$ is a unital subring where $R$ is an ideal, it follows for any element $s \in S$ that $s=s 1\in R$ hence $R=S$. Hence the only unital subring $R$ which is an ideal is the trivial sub ring $R=S$. **QED**

**Example 1.** Let $S:=\mathbb{Q}$ be the field of rational numbers. Let $R \subseteq S$ be a unital sub ring which is an ideal. This means that for any element $x\in R$ and any element $s\in S$ it follws $sx \in R$. Since $1\in R$ this implies that $s1 =s \in R$ hence $R=S$.

**Example 2.** If $S$ is any unital associative ring and $R \subseteq S$ is an ideal then $R \subseteq S$ is a (non-unital) sub ring.

**Proof:** Since $R$ is an ideal, it follows $R$ is closed under addition and for any $s\in S, x\in R$ it follows $sx\in R$. In particular for any $s,x\in R$ it follows $sx\in R$ hence $R$ has a multiplication. It follows $R$ is a (non-unital) associative sub ring of $S$.

**Definition.** Let $R^{id}$ be the set of elements (finite sums) $\sum_i s_ix_i$ with $s_i \in S, x_i \in R$.

It follows $R  \subseteq R^{id}$ and $R^{id}\subseteq S$ is an ideal in $S$.

**Lemma.** $R$ is an ideal in $S$ iff $R=R^{id}$.

**Proof:** If $R$ is an ideal is tollows $R^{id} \subseteq R$ by definition. If $R=R^{id}$ it follows $R$ is an ideal. **QED**

Hence the ideal $R^{id}$ measures when the ring $R$ is an ideal. You may define the abelian group $R^{id}/R$. By the above argument it has the property that $R^{id}/R=0$ iff $R$ is an ideal, hence the quotient $R^{id}/R$ "detects" when $R$ is an ideal.